# Skipping the first variable(s) when doing multiple assignment in Ruby

Tags: ruby, split, variable-assignment

I know that I can split a string and assign the different parts to different variables in one line in Ruby:

```
a, b, c, d = "this is a string".split
puts a # => "this"
puts b # => "is"
puts c # => "a"
puts d # => "string"
```

But what if I don't care about the first *x* parts of the result, and only want to save the later parts to variables? E.g. in the above example, what if I want to save "a" and "string" to variables but don't care about "this" and "is"?

I realise I could just keep my code as it is and never use the variables `a` and `b` but that seems ugly to me. Does Ruby have a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: Use a variable you don't care about (e.g. `_, _, c, d = ..`) or adjust the input (e.g. `.. = "this is a string".split()[2,-1]`)

Comment: @user2864740, that's the way to do it.  Please post that as an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Several ways.

```
_, _, a, b = "this is a string".split
```

Or,

```
"this is a string".split[2, 3]
```

Or, really, just about any other way you want; they'll all do roughly the same thing and what's important is the semantics you want to leave for the maintainer.

Comment: Isn't this the same as suggested in @user2864740's earlier comment?

Comment: These both work. I didn't realise that you can pass arguments to `split`. Also, I didn't like the "junk variables" option because vim gives me an "unused variable" warning, but it turns out that it doesn't do this for `_`. Perfecto!

Comment: @GeorgeMillo, just to be clear, that's not an "argument" to `split`, that's an array slice of the results of `split`

@CarySwoveland first off, someone leaving a comment doesn't preclude including that comment in an answer. Secondly, I offered him another way, too, and mentioned there were several others.

Comment: You suggested precisely the same two approaches that were in the comment.  You can of course present a comment as your answer. The question is whether you should.

Comment: Oh no, please don't steal his precious Internet points! But yeah @Bandrami you're right, I missed that those were square not round brackets.

Comment: George, my comment had nothing to do with points. There are many members of SO who don't give a whit about points.  They participate only because they want to help others and for the personal satisfaction of wrestling a problem to the ground.   @user2864740 may well be one, considering that he/she offered a suggestion in the form of a comment, rather than answer.  You response should have been a 'thank you', not a mocking remark.

Comment: And there are many users (like me) who tend not to read comments, and post answers to unanswered questions.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.slice` method to get the last 2 elements.

```
c, d  = "this is a string".split.slice(-2, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a slightly different case where in the string I was parsing I cared about "this", "is", and "string", but not about "a". The dummy variable approach worked, but I'm curious whether there's an array slicing syntax that would have. `"this is a string".split[0, 1, 3]` did not (error: too many arguments)

Edit: answered my own question with a little digging. `"this is a string".split.values_at(0, 1, 3)` Putting it in an answer in case anyone else needs this kind of cherry picking.